# Sed command usage without defining variables in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, sed

I have two variables

```
source_repo="fdl_ppe_01_04_repos_svc"
target_repo="fdl_ppe_01_10_repos_svc"
```

and I currently do a substitution within an XML file to replace all instances of $source_repo with $target_repo:

```
sed "s/$source_repo/$target_repo/g" $1 > $1_changed
```

How do I format the sed command so that it matches the pattern "fdl_ppe_01_XX_repos_svc" and replaces with $target_repo 
(XX can only be two digits)

...basically I don't want to have to define $source_repo in the script anymore

I'm struggling to understand sed syntax, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `source_repo="fdl_ppe_01_[0-9][0-9]_repos_svc"`, and always double quote your variable `"$1"`.

Comment: Many thanks for the super fast response!  Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used character matching in your sed command:

Character Class - [:digit:] = Numeric digits [0-9]

> sed "s/fdl_ppe_01_[0-9][0-9]_repos_svc/$target_repo/g" $1 >
>   $1_changed

$1_changed will give you desired output I believe.